# Ajax One Page Portfolio with Full view

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have seen lot of websites having a portfolio with thumbnails. When you click on a thumbnail, the detail page opens at the top of the same page and has navigation and close buttons. You can see an example here:

http://demo.themezilla.com/garnish/

I have found that this is done with AJAX. I have searched on google, but couldn't find any plugins that do this. So I went through the source code, but I couldn't understood how it is done.

Is there any simple way to achieve the same with close, next & previous. Or any plugin?

Comment: There are loads of JavaScript based gallery solutions.

Comment: All of them are lightboxes. It will be great if you give the working link.

Answer (score -1):

As I see it they are using [Fancybox](http://fancybox.net/) or maybe [Fancybox2](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/).

UPDATE It is quite interesting how it works. They store all the content in a separate page and they are showing DIVs form that [page](http://demo.themezilla.com/garnish/wp-content/themes/garnish/includes/home-magicdoor.php).

Additionally [SlideJS](http://slidesjs.com/) is quite close to the gallery you need. And it is *not* a lightbox, it is an inline slideshow library (also included in the Garnish theme).

Comment: It's true that fancybox is included in the source code, it's not the answer to the question. Fancybox is a lightbox.

Comment: How is that my fault? He wants the same gallery feature as it is on that site and that's done with Fancybox, which is lightbox alternative.

Comment: @iblamefish Actually _Fancybox_ is a lightbox alternative...That being said, this still does not answer the OP's question. The weren't asking what the site they linked to used. They were asking for plugins or source code that would achieve the same results...